# Facebook share button code return empty page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I’m pulling my hair out to make a simple Facebook like button. Titter took 10 seconds, I just copied and pasted the code. it worked. I have spent four hours trying to find out why the Facebook code does not work. (I don’t know Javascript BTW).

I got this code from Facebook:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) 
      return;
  js = d.createElement(s); 
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=1395309104022728&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And this html:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"></div>
```

But if I paste it all into a test html file, the result is a black page. Do I need to change it (add an app id?) or what? I'm Confused.

Comment: try uploading it to your host, and run from there. certain javascript features won't work on localhost.

Comment: That was it! Simples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have a relative url for sdk.js which won't work on file system. you need http protocol i.e. run it on a hosting site:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=1395309104022728&version=v2.0";
```

Comment: oh... it was so obvious I cant believe just I didn't see it